# Creating "fly-in" effect in Sprite-kit for SKLabels

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction, sklabelnode

I would like to create this effect:

http://d.pr/v/4oGc

Here in details:

[image]
[image]
[image]

in sprite-kit with `SKLabelNode`. So basically I would like the labels to "fly in". My first thought was to use `SKAction` for this but I didn't figure out if it actually can be applied this way.

Any tips for recreating that effect in Spritekit?

Comment: SKAction should work. SKAction.moveTo or SKAction.followPath may suit your needs

Comment: From what I see in your link, all HUD elements share a single parent node. On this node you can run `[SKAction scaleTo:]` and `[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:]` simultaneously (`[SKAction group:]`) to achieve desired effect.

Comment: That's right! I'll make answer out of this!

Comment: You must insert some pictures to explain what you want to do, not only a link, it can be unavailable so your question become unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in your link, all HUD elements share a single parent node.

On this node you can run `[SKAction scaleTo:]` and `[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:]` simultaneously `([SKAction group:])` to achieve desired effect. – CloakedEddy

Comment: What are you doing? You answer your question with the comments of other user? Remove your question and re-creat a question with answer.

Comment: What's the problem? I find CloakedEddy's comment to be the answer to my question and therefore to make it easier for others who should read this question, make the answering comment an answer. There is no point duplicating the question as a new question.